# Number of httpd processes and prefork.c

Tags: httpd, oom, oom-killer

Hi I got OOM killer problems which caused:
[mpm_prefork:error] [pid 18103] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process

I had to restart the server to get it working.

In /var/log/messages near the OOM killer messages it showed the running processes.

There were 140-160 processes of httpd running.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf includes:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers       10
    MaxClients            100
    ServerLimit           100
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

I thought this would limit the number of httpd processes to 100?

From /var/log/messages:

```
May 17 08:54:47 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.202712] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.206073] 359 total pagecache pages
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.207550] 0 pages in swap cache
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.208898] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.211080] Free swap  = 0kB
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.212467] Total swap = 0kB
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.213700] 524189 pages RAM
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.214916] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.216427] 11362 pages reserved
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.217763] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.221141] [ 1527]     0  1527     2865      230      11       3        0         -1000 udevd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.224563] [ 2037]     0  2037     2340      125      10       3        0             0 dhclient
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.228241] [ 2120]     0  2120    62059     1234      24       3        0             0 rsyslogd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.231735] [ 2149]    81  2149     5447       61      15       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.235328] [ 2289]     0  2289     5621       58      17       3        0             0 xinetd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.238711] [ 2331]     0  2331    22246      463      45       3        0             0 sendmail
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.242348] [ 2340]    51  2340    20111      370      40       3        0             0 sendmail
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.245888] [ 2367]     0  2367    29888      157      16       4        0             0 crond
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.249419] [ 2381]     0  2381     4266       39      14       3        0             0 atd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.252685] [ 2432]     0  2432     1614       29       8       3        0             0 agetty
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.256350] [ 2433]     0  2433     1077       22       8       3        0             0 mingetty
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.259756] [ 2436]     0  2436     1077       22       7       3        0             0 mingetty
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.263167] [ 2439]     0  2439     1077       23       8       3        0             0 mingetty
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.267901] [ 2441]     0  2441     1077       23       8       3        0             0 mingetty
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.271350] [ 2443]     0  2443     1077       22       8       3        0             0 mingetty
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.274733] [ 2445]     0  2445     1077       23       7       3        0             0 mingetty
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.278528] [18103]     0 18103   111419     2632     204       4        0             0 httpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.282315] [ 6601]     0  6601    19985      205      41       3        0         -1000 sshd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.285707] [ 6633]     0  6633    13238      108      26       3        0         -1000 auditd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.289151] [ 2642]    38  2642     7323      141      18       3        0             0 ntpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.292594] [ 6658]    48  6658   139739     6636     221       4        0             0 httpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.296161] [ 6662]    48  6662   138636     6634     220       4        0             0 httpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.299436] [ 6666]    48  6666   188897     6662     238       4        0             0 httpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.302676] [ 6670]    48  6670   139739     6725     221       4        0             0 httpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.306148] [ 6673]    48  6673   139730     6627     221       4        0             0 httpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.309594] [ 6678]    48  6678   138561     5454     219       4        0             0 httpd
May 17 08:54:49 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [5955601.313091] [ 6701]    48  6701   139729     6629     221       4        0             0 httpd
.......
```

.......

Comment: "There were 140-160 processes of httpd running": the output you provided has NO evidence of this. How are you sure about the supposed-previously-running more-than-Maxclient apache processes?

Comment: The "From /var/log/messages" excerpt had 140-160 lines with "httpd" in it... I assume that was a list of the processes that were running at the time... this list appeared a few times when the OOM killer was running

Answer (score 0):

Error `Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process` said that you don't have free Virtual memory on your server, more about virtual memory you could read in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/138625/327632). OOM killer do it work, when system couldn't use more Resident Memory then it exist in system, size of Resident Memory calculated as RAM+Swap. You don't have swap at all.

So easiest solution for you - add additional swap. How to do it mentioned in this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps).