# Apache2 using insane amounts of memory

Tags: nginx, memory, apache2

On a server with 30GB of memory serving somewhat high-volume traffic.

For some reason recently Apache2 has started running threads with insane memory usage. 500MB-750MB per thread is not uncommon right now.

php.ini has `memory_limit = 128M` (php7.0 default).

Apache prefork config is on defaults.

The result is that we're running with only ~1GB of free memory.

What am I missing?

We have Nginx proxying requests and it's processes are more like ~60MB per thread. Here is a screenshot of running `top`

[Top Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCg6A.jpg)

Any insight as to what could be driving this is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that top output it looks like Apache processes have 20-50MB "res" (resident) in memory. The "virt" [isn't memory you need to worry about](https://serverfault.com/questions/138427/top-what-does-virtual-memory-size-mean-linux-ubuntu), generally, it can be mapped files and isn't actual RAM used.

I can see that you have 28GB of memory "cached". This is typically cached files. This is a good thing, it saves the OS from having to go to the disk to access files.

I think you may benefit from the "[Linux Ate My RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)" website.

What exactly is the problem this is causing? Does your system every report "out of memory", or processes fail because of lack of RAM?

Comment: The cached memory thing makes sense now. Sorry - I'm not much of an infrastructure guy. Biggest challenge is having nginx 504 timeouts recently - trying to narrow down the possible performance bottlenecks.

Comment: For your 504's, you might try to capture `netstat -aeenp` as root periodically during these times.  Count the number of connections in time wait, close wait, etc.  This is sometimes hard to spot in logs.  If that is the issue, I can offer suggestions for a way around it.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding. Suggest you gather information and post a question about the timeouts. curl showing the problem, applicable logs, and configurations would be key information to share.

Comment: You probably mean MB, not KB up there, since the numbers are in kilobytes already.

Comment: Thanks @TollefFogHeen, I wasn't sure what the units were

Comment: @TollefFogHeen - Wouldn't 668084 under VIRT translate to 668MB since it's in KB in `top` already?

Comment: @Aaron - Great suggestion. I will look at this and let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: @Wes, correct, but VIRT isn't very interesting, you want to look at RES. See the answer and links. :-)

Comment: @TollefFogHeen Thanks for helping me understand that. Looking at the RES numbers, it seems much more normal. Not an infrastructure guy but that's definitely helpful.