# Using `top` command shows PHP FPM processes using more memory than available

Tags: php-fpm, memory-usage, top

I've read [this answer about understanding `top`](https://superuser.com/a/575330/749806), as well as `man top`, but I think I still have trouble turning the presented data from `top` into actual information.

I'm logged on an Amazon EC2 instance which is part of a load-balanced group. It's running PHP FPM and I've filtered `top` to show only the `php-fpm` processes:

```
top - 11:27:43 up 18:59,  2 users,  load average: 0.59, 0.79, 0.74
Tasks: 171 total,   1 running, 125 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  9.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 90.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   1935.6 total,    177.7 free,    692.3 used,   1065.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   1052.0 avail Mem

  PID USER            PR    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                   
 1566 root            20  356.2m  30.5m  23.5m S        1.6   0:02.14 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
 2188 webapp          20  442.2m  51.3m  31.8m S        2.7   2:18.47 php-fpm: pool www
 2189 webapp          20  442.1m  50.8m  30.4m S        2.6   2:19.21 php-fpm: pool www
 2190 webapp          20  444.2m  52.6m  30.4m S        2.7   2:20.14 php-fpm: pool www
 2191 webapp          20  442.1m  51.1m  31.3m S        2.6   2:22.69 php-fpm: pool www
 2192 webapp          20  442.2m  50.8m  31.6m S        2.6   2:19.64 php-fpm: pool www
 2193 webapp          20  436.3m  46.5m  32.0m S        2.4   2:17.29 php-fpm: pool www
 2194 webapp          20  452.2m  60.6m  30.4m S        3.1   2:19.82 php-fpm: pool www
 2195 webapp          20  438.1m  48.0m  31.6m S        2.5   2:17.78 php-fpm: pool www
 2197 webapp          20  442.2m  50.9m  30.6m S        2.6   2:18.28 php-fpm: pool www
12626 webapp          20  443.6m  50.4m  28.4m S        2.6   0:37.02 php-fpm: pool www
12627 webapp          20  443.5m  50.3m  28.6m S        2.6   0:35.68 php-fpm: pool www
12628 webapp          20  438.0m  45.1m  29.1m S        2.3   0:36.28 php-fpm: pool www
12629 webapp          20  443.9m  51.4m  29.3m S        2.7   0:35.26 php-fpm: pool www
12630 webapp          20  441.6m  48.9m  29.5m S        2.5   0:34.90 php-fpm: pool www
12631 webapp          20  443.6m  50.5m  28.7m S        2.6   0:34.93 php-fpm: pool www
12632 webapp          20  436.0m  43.2m  29.1m S        2.2   0:36.01 php-fpm: pool www
12635 webapp          20  441.6m  48.1m  28.3m S        2.5   0:34.56 php-fpm: pool www
12636 webapp          20  446.1m  55.0m  30.8m S        2.8   0:37.10 php-fpm: pool www
12637 webapp          20  441.9m  48.8m  29.0m S        2.5   0:35.16 php-fpm: pool www
12639 webapp          20  443.6m  50.3m  28.5m S        2.6   0:34.23 php-fpm: pool www
12640 webapp          20  438.0m  44.7m  28.9m S        2.3   0:36.33 php-fpm: pool www
12641 webapp          20  442.8m  49.5m  28.4m S        2.6   0:35.51 php-fpm: pool www
12642 webapp          20  443.8m  50.8m  29.1m S        2.6   0:36.22 php-fpm: pool www
12643 webapp          20  438.0m  44.2m  29.2m S        2.3   0:33.49 php-fpm: pool www
12644 webapp          20  440.0m  47.4m  29.3m S        2.5   0:36.44 php-fpm: pool www
12645 webapp          20  441.6m  48.7m  29.0m S        2.5   0:34.38 php-fpm: pool www
12646 webapp          20  441.6m  48.5m  28.8m S        2.5   0:34.53 php-fpm: pool www
12647 webapp          20  437.6m  44.5m  28.5m S        2.3   0:34.73 php-fpm: pool www
12648 webapp          20  437.7m  44.4m  28.6m S        2.3   0:33.64 php-fpm: pool www
12649 webapp          20  440.0m  46.9m  29.0m S        2.4   0:35.81 php-fpm: pool www
12651 webapp          20  444.1m  51.1m  29.0m S        2.6   0:34.77 php-fpm: pool www
12652 webapp          20  439.8m  47.0m  29.1m S        2.4   0:35.02 php-fpm: pool www
12657 webapp          20  443.9m  51.7m  29.9m S        2.7   0:35.35 php-fpm: pool www
12658 webapp          20  438.0m  45.5m  29.3m S        2.3   0:34.81 php-fpm: pool www
12667 webapp          20  441.9m  49.6m  29.6m S        2.6   0:34.21 php-fpm: pool www
```

Here's what I don't understand:

1. What does the `VIRT` column display *actually*? I understand that it's virtual memory, but on line 2 of the memory summary, I can see that there's `1052.0 avail Mem`, while the processes in the `VIRT` column sum up to way more than that.
2. How is there `1052.0` of available swap/virtual memory, while there's `0.0` total?
3. How is there only `692.3` memory used, when the sum of the `%MEM` column is `88.6%`? Shouldn't it be at least `1935 * 0.886 = 1714`? It looks like I get close to that number if I add in the `1065.7 buff/cache` to those `692.3`, but what's the reason behind that?
4. Why is the master process sleeping (as indicated by the `S` column)? Shouldn't at least *it* be running?

### My main concern

The `memory_limit` setting in PHP ini is set to `256M`. That should mean that each child process spawned by FPM could use up to that much memory, correct? If that's right and I have 35 child processes (as currently shown by `top`), then theoretically they could use (or attempt to use) up to `35 * 256 = 8960M` memory. That's way more than the `1935M` I have in total.

Also, the total sum of memory in the `RES` column is `1749.6`. In other words, the used memory is `1749/1935 = 90.38%`. But that's when all processes are in a sleep state! If there's a spike in traffic and memory consumption suddenly goes up, that sounds disastrous.

I think about reducing the allowed memory from `256M` to `128M` and reducing `pm.max_children` from the default `50` to, say, `12`. This way, the total possible memory consumption of PHP FPM would be `12 * 128 = 1536M`, which will be within the actual available memory on the system. Does that make sense?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/138427/what-does-virtual-memory-size-in-top-mean summarised *"VIRT has nothing to do with actual RAM usage"*

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider. Firstly, you see `692.3 used`, but you also need to factor in `1065.7 buff/cache`. If you sum the `RES` column it should align with the total of `used` and `buff/cache`. This is because `buff/cache` represents data used for those processes, and while not immediately available, should be available shortly.

As to `memory_limit` and `pm.max_children`:
You can run the most resource hungry script in your app and measure its memory usage using [a memory_get_peak_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php).

Take that value, add in some capacity for growth of your dataset, and now you have a realistic maximum memory needed per script. With that figure you can now estimate the `pm.max_children` your server can handle. Adjust this figure down to allow for other processes on your server.

You can also now set a more accurate `memory_limit` - but be aware breaching this value will cause your script to die. I find it often works best as a control to stop runaway scripts from killing your service, and set it higher than my most memory demanding scripts to allow for future, more complex jobs.

You should also check the fpm (pm.*) variables and adjust accordingly.